# Visual Studio custom data visualizer throws BadImageFormatException

Tags: visual-studio, 64-bit, debuggervisualizer

In our c# code base (hence managed code), we have a class that we make extensive use of throughout the code.
Given its ubiquity, I decided to write a custom debugger visualizer so that we could easily examine such objects when debugging.
But, I hit a snag - when I try to run the visualizer in the IDE, I get a `BadImageFormatException`.

I am posting this to help others who come across the same error.  I know what the issue and solution is and will post.

Comment: You might want to ponder a bit why Microsoft's visualizers don't have that problem.  You are doing it wrong, the question is not good enough to tell how.  We can't even tell if this is a visualizer for C++ or managed code.  Guessing at the latter, the solution platform is irrelevant, only the Project > Properties > Build settings matter.

Comment: @hans-passant  Would love to know then how to do it correctly when the build target on the application being built is x64.  Can you point me somewhere?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (as of Visual Studio 2019) it's possible to [split the visualizer into two](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/visualizer-architecture):

1. **debuggee-side DLL** -- gets injected into the target process, and
2. **debugger-side DLL** -- loaded into Visual Studio.

The two halves pass data between each other using serialization/deserialization.

This architecture is required for visualizers to target multiple frameworks -- the debugger side is loaded into Visual Studio, so it must target .NET Framework; the debuggee side is injected into the target process, which might target .NET Core or .NET 5+. (I refer you to [this repo](https://github.com/zspitz/SimpleDateTimeVisualizer) for a minimal visualizer with this structure; and to other visualizers I've written ([1](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeVisualizer) [2](https://github.com/zspitz/DateTimeVisualizer)) which also use a similar architecture.)

The same architecture works for bit-ness. Visual Studio is a 32-bit application, so the debugger side cannot be 64-bit; it must be 32-bit or AnyCPU. But if the target process might be 64-bit, the debuggee side has to match the target process and must be 64-bit or AnyCPU.

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-install-a-visualizer?view=vs-2019#to-install-a-visualizer-for-visual-studio-2019):

> Typically, it is best if both the debugger-side DLL and the debuggee-side DLL specify **Any CPU** as the target platform. The debugger-side DLL must be either **Any CPU** or **32-bit**. The target platform for the debuggee-side DLL should correspond to the debugee process.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231344/discussion-between-zev-spitz-and-david-i-mcintosh).

Comment: The visualizers which Zev Spitz references above are well worth checking out.  Thanks for these Zev! There are also other references with lots of information.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Visual Studio itself, the IDE, runs as a 32-bit process only.  If it is to run a custom data visualizer for you while debugging, the custom visualizer and all the code that this visualizer loads must be loadable and runnable by a 32-bit process.  The custom visualizer gets the object to visualize by a serialization/deserialization process.  To deserialize the object, the visualizer must be able to load the .dll in which the object is defined.  And here we run in to the snag: if we are building our application to an x64 target (rather than an AnyCpu target), we’re up a creek – it doesn’t matter if the custom visualizer itself is built to a 32-bit target, because ***it’s the application code that must be used for deserialization***.

So if your application is built to a 64-bit target, you cannot run a custom visualizer (big, big OUCH Microsoft!).  To get around the snag, you can build to a target of AnyCpu, and then things work well: the application loads and runs as 64-bit (since targeted to AnyCpu), but the IDE is still able to load the .dll’s as 32-bit for the purposes of the custom data visualizer running in the IDE’s process space.

If I am wrong on this and there is a better work-around, I would love to be corrected!  Thanks.